# visual studio 13 cordova CTP3 - BLD folder readonly

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

We recently updated Visual Studio 2013 to update 4. We uninstalled the Cordova Hybrid CTP2 and then installed the new Cordova CTP3. It seems that after cleaning a Cordova project and deleting the BLD folder, we are able to build the project successfully (only one time). However, the next time we attempt to build, visual studio is unable to write to the BLD folder as it has become read-only. If we manually set the BLD folder as -r, we can again build once successfully but it again becomes +r. This seems to have been introduced with CTP3. Visual Studio does not expose any "pre-build" options for cordova projects so we are unable to make our own correction to this. Is there a fix or work-around available for this?

Comment: Have you manage to solve this problem ? I did what you said in the answer below but still no joy...

Answer (score 1):

I found the fix - the FAQ posted my Microsoft has a fix for another symptom which in turn corrects this issue. [Open CTP2.0 project in VS](http://www.visualstudio.com/explore/cordova-faq-vs)

```html
The imported project "C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

Then open the jsproj file in the editor (Right-click and select Edit myproject.jsproj) and modify the path in following lines: 
<Import Project="$(AppData)\npm\node_modules\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets" /> 
<Import Project="$(AppData)\npm\node_modules\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.TypeScript.MDA.targets" />

To look like these: 
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets" /> 
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.TypeScript.MDA.targets" />
```